# Mathematical Mystery 1

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge

I come before V when I open up to you

You focus on a point and get directed to a line too

My cone isn't delicious to many a high schooler

If only compared to hyperbolic humor I was cooler

Name this mathematical object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's a

> Parabola

I come before V when I open up to you

> It's shaped like a letter U when it opens upward, which is the letter before V in the alphabet.

You focus on a point and get directed to a line too

> Focus (a point) and directrix (a line) of a parabola

My cone isn't delicious to many a high schooler

> Not sure about this; maybe because a parabola is a conic section of a cone?

If only compared to hyperbolic humor I was cooler

> Hyperbolas look similar to parabolas

Comment: Yep, the 3rd line refers to a hatred of mathematics by many high schoolers, also the 1st line was originally going to use the term "concave upward" to confuse people, but the rhyming wouldn't work.

Comment: I thought about a variable named u because it was before v

Comment: @XavierStanton Ohh yeah "concave upward" would've been cool. Not sure if maybe "concave upward" is too specific to parabolas, but "open up" works great for this puzzle too

Comment: "Concave Upward" is the technical term, especially in calculus